# Swift iOS how selected data to a table

Tags: ios, swift, selected

How do I do it when if status is equal to static I don't want to show it in the table? Code is below. I only wanted to show all the data but not the data with `status == "static"`.

```
Response [["status": {
    name = static;
}, "sched": 2015-01-01T08:00:00+08:00, "desc": Brush your teeth, "id": 249, "reward": 1.00, "parent": , "child": , "date_created": 2018-04-25T14:27:20.405928+08:00, "name": aBrush your teeth, "occurrence": {
    name = once;
}, "type": , "date_modified": 2018-04-26T11:56:02.030647+08:00], ["status": {
    name = static;
}, "sched": 2015-01-01T08:00:00+08:00, "desc": Brush your teeth, "id": 250, "reward": 1.00, "parent": , "child": , "date_created": 2018-04-25T14:28:49.780354+08:00, "name": Brush your teeth, "occurrence": {
    name = once;
}, "type": , "date_modified": 2018-04-26T11:56:05.616333+08:00], ["status": {
    name = static;
}, "sched": 2015-01-01T08:00:00+08:00, "desc": Brush your teeth, "id": 252, "reward": 1.00, "parent": , "child": , "date_created": 2018-04-25T14:31:02.274405+08:00, "name": Brush your teeth, "occurrence": {
    name = once;
}, "type": , "date_modified": 2018-04-26T11:59:57.676148+08:00], ["status": {
    name = static;
}, "sched": 2015-01-01T08:00:00+08:00, "desc": Brush your teeth, "id": 253, "reward": 1.00, "parent": , "child": , "date_created": 2018-04-25T14:34:37.097498+08:00, "name": Brush your teeth, "occurrence": {
    name = once;
}, "type": , "date_modified": 2018-04-26T09:42:24.633359+08:00], ["status": {
    name = static;
}, "sched": 2015-01-01T08:00:00+08:00, "desc": Brush your teeths, "id": 254, "reward": 1.00, "parent": , "child": , "date_created": 2018-04-25T14:36:53.766088+08:00, "name": Brush your teeth, "occurrence": {
    name = once;
}, "type": , "date_modified": 2018-04-26T11:56:15.757769+08:00], ["status": {
    name = ongoing;
}, "sched": 2018-04-19T15:54:24.657644+08:00, "desc": {
  "questions" : [
    {
      "b" : 2,
      "a" : 1
    },
    {
      "b" : 3,
      "a" : 2
    },
    {
      "b" : 2,
      "a" : 8
    },
    {
      "b" : 9,
      "a" : 7
    },
    {
      "b" : 3,
      "a" : 6
    }
  ],
  "operation" : "+"
}, "id": 260, "reward": 1.00, "parent": shit, "child": , "date_created": 2018-04-26T10:13:42.913149+08:00, "name": chorename, "occurrence": {
    name = once;
}, "type": homework, "date_modified": 2018-04-26T10:13:42.953485+08:00]]


       if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row] {
            print("All Result: " , getTempDetails)
            if let str = getTempDetails["status"] as? [String: String] {
                if let name = str["name"] {
                    if name == "ongoing" {
                        cell.toDoItemLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as? String
                        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = created

//                        cell.label.textColor =  UIColor(red: 0.9294, green: 0.3333, blue: 0.1804, alpha: 1.0)
//                        cell.backgroundColor = created


                    }else if name == "approved" {
                       cell.toDoItemLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as? String
                       cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = done
                    }
                    else if name == "for approval" {
                        cell.toDoItemLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as? String
                        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = pending
                    }else if name == "near expiry" {
                       cell.toDoItemLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as? String
                       cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = neardue
                    } else if name == "expired" {
                        cell.toDoItemLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as? String
                        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = expired
                    }else if  name == "static" {
                       cell.toDoItemLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as? String
                        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.7686, green: 0.4235, blue: 0.3725, alpha: 1.0)
//
                    } else {
                        print("false")
                       cell.toDoItemLabel.text = "lols"
                    }
                }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Before passing data to tableview methods, you must have to remove entries from getTempDetails dictionary which you don't want.. means create same dictionary with removing data where name == "static"... and use newly created dictionary for table

Comment: can you post the asnwer sir so i can upvote

Comment: Can you please show The JSON From which you are getting all this , So it will be easy to write a format, casting status as dictionary in **getTempDetails["status"] as? [String: String] ** but you are saying  **status to be not of type Static** bit unclear

Comment: i have updated the question above

Comment: i want to show all status expect status  == static

Comment: @AkornDurnKurvirck you can simply make an seperate array of it with status != Static and show that only, And reload the tableView each time when you get a new data. Can you please explain where your code is not working so that i can make a one for you

Comment: if status == static dont show it to table Sir that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not create a cell if you don't want to show it. If you are, you are making unnecessary extra calls.

If you are currently returning the total count of your datasource at `numberOfRowsInSection`, you must return the count of items with `status != "static"` instead. This way the `cellForRowAt` will be called the correct amount of times.

Then, you have 2 options:

1. Have a separate datasource which doesn't contain items with `status == "static"` and use it directly at `cellForRowAt`;
2. Filter, at `cellForRowAt`, your current datasource, so that it returns only the correct items.

Comment: this is my numberOfRowsInSection code   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return getAllDetail.count
        }

Comment: getAllDetail holds what type object?

Comment: guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}
                    print("Response \(json)")
                    for item in json {
                        
                        self.getAllDetail.append(item)

Comment: which properties does your item have?

Comment: what properties do you mean ?

Comment: Variables, arrays, etc

Comment: var getAllDetail: [[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]]()

Comment: You shoul filter the getAllDetail on `numberOfRowsInSection` based on the property you want to exclude, which is `status == "static"`, then return the `count` of filtered version of getAllDetail. I recommend taking a look at the filter section in the following article: https://craiggrummitt.com/2017/05/08/higher-order-functions-in-swift/

Comment: i cant go to chat low reput

Answer (score 0):

Before passing data to tableview methods, you must have to remove entries from getTempDetails dictionary which you don't want.. means create same dictionary with removing data where name == "static"... and use newly created dictionary for table

Comment: what you mean by that Sir ?

Comment: Means you are using getTempDetails dictionary in cellForRowAtIndex... Don't use this. Make another dictionary by removing unwanted data and then use that newly created dictionary for cellForRowAtIndex

Comment: Don't write your unwanted data removing logic in Tableview method.. Make wanted data dictionary and then call tableview