# swift ios trigger a table index when button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, selectedindex

I have a button in my table and when it was click it will trigger the selected table index. for example when i click the button at a selected index it will trigger the code below. Thank You

code

```
func indexWasPressed(cell: ToDoListTableViewCell) {
 trigger it here
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code to get index from TableViewCell:

```
func indexWasPressed(cell: ToDoListTableViewCell) {
    let indexPath = yourTableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    let index = indexPath.row
}
```

Comment: it was working sir but i what if i want to trigger this unc tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {? when button is pressed?

Comment: Ok Means on click of cell button you have to get cell index right? Then you have to implement delegate

Comment: can you please answer this sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033748/swift-ios-how-selected-data-to-a-table

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
 @objc func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    // printing selected row
  print("index path: \(sender.tag)")

    //do you want section try this
   var section = Int()

    let pointInTable: CGPoint = sender.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: self.tblView)
    let cellIndexPath = self.tblView.indexPathForRow(at: pointInTable)
    section(cellIndexPath!)
    section = cellIndexPath!.row
    print(section)


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print("cell for rows in \(indexPath.section)")


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifire", for: indexPath) as! yourcell

        cell.yourbutton.tag = indexpath.row

        cell.yourbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonpressed(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        }
```